# Test Project can't find Main Project's Public Classes

Tags: c#, wpf, resharper, visual-studio-2017

Running Visual Studio 2017 v4.6.01586, latest version of Resharper 2017.1.1, C# WPF project.

I have my Main project with public classes in it, can definitely access them internally in the project no problem.

Today I created a Test Project in my solution, and added the reference to my main project.

When I went to create an instance of one of my public classes from my main project in my test project, it was not able to be found.

```
public class TestBase
{
    private static Thing foo = new Thing();
}
```

Thing is just shown Red and totally nonfunctional. Resharper suggests the following:

- "Reference MainProject and use 'Thing'"
- "Create Type Thing"
- "Create nest Type Thing"

... etc etc

When I click "Reference MainProject and use 'Thing'", nothing happens. Thing continues to stay red and Resharper keeps suggesting to do the same things.

I tried closing all the windows, refreshing Resharper's Cache, closing and opening the project, cleaning the solution and rebuilding, all to no avail.

Update: Manually clearing all of the cache in Resharper's AppData folder temporarily fixes my problem for about 30 seconds.

When I resume Resharper, my classes are found and working. But about thirty seconds later they go back to being red. So this is clearly a resharper problem.

Comment: Just wild-guessing: have you specified the original classes namespace? Since you just write Thing, you need to have a using statement in the test project files.

Comment: Yeah, even the using statement just goes red like it can't find what its looking for unfortunately.

Comment: Just to be sure, when adding the reference, did you just select the line and pressed ok or did you actually check the checkbox at the beginning of the line containing your main project in the add reference dialog?

Comment: When I open Project -> Dependencies -> Projects, I can see my project listed there. When I right click Dependencies and click 'Add reference', my main project is checked off in Reference Manager. When I do a Using statement on the main project namespace in my test project however, it just turns red and Resharper gives me "Cannot resolve symbol"